# jquery tmpl() returns empty string

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using a jquery mobile a template to create a list of links from list of objects

The object i'm passing have userName, comment and image. 
The template is

```
<script id="commentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<li>
    <a href="http://mydomain/sub/sub">
        <img src="{{= url }}" alt="{{= username }}"/>

        <p>{{= username }} - {{= usercomment }}</p>
    </a>
</li>
</script>
```

Now when I go to the page which have the js calling this page using a link from other page, the template returns empty string, but when I go to the page by typing the url in the browser address bar the template works like charm. let me give an example:

1. I'm in the 
   http://www.mh.mh/home page and click a link to go to http://www.mh.mh/comments, the template returns empty string for all comments.
2. I type http://www.mh.mh/comments in the browser and press enter the template returns the correct values and create the links for the comments.

any explanation why is this happening?

Comment: Where in your code do you define your template?

Comment: In a page that being called from the master layout page.

Answer (score 0):

When changing page, jquery mobile will only load the body of the target page, and ignore the headers. This  means that any code you will want to use in your pages has to be loaded in your pages has to be loaded in your first page.
There are two direct consequences :
 - the header of your first page should contain all the information that would have been on the header of subsequent pages (link to CSS and js files for instance)
 - any page that could be the first page (think of direct URL input or even refreshes) should have such a header

Comment: "When changing page, jquery mobile will only load the body of the target page", i import the template in the body of the main layout page. However, your comment made me think what if I imported the template directly to the required page instead of the master page?! I tried it and it worked! this solves my problem for now but I don't understand why it does not work when it's in the master page. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you detail where (either which html page, or which .js and where it is linked from) you define the template, and call $.tmpl() ?